# DataGrids over ScrollViewer prevent it to scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus, scrollviewer

I have multiples DataGrids disposed over a ScrollViewer.
These DataGrids have an "height: auto" property so that I can hide the scrollbar and view all the content.
The only problem is that the DataGrids takes the focus and so I can't scroll the ScrollViewer.
Is that a property to keep the focus on the ScrollViewer but also keeping the behaviour of the DataGrids (so I can select elements) ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran across this exact same issue except my scenario was a little bit more complicated. Instead of having DataGrid in a ScrollViewer, I had a bunch of UserControl (called ProductDataGrid and defined below) in my ScrollViewer:

ProductDataGrid.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Control.ProductDataGrid" ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="Header" Grid.Row="0" ... />

        <DataGrid x:Name="ProductData" Grid.Row="1" ... />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ProductPortfolioListView.xaml:

```
<Page ...
      xmlns:my="clr-namespace:My.Control"
      ....>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ProductScrollViewer">
            <StackPanel>
                <my:ProductDataGrid ... />

                <my:ProductDataGrid ... />

                <my:ProductDataGrid ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

The solution provided by Livsi is spot on correct but my UserControl did not have access to my ScrollViewer, so here is my solution:

ProductPortfolioListView.xaml:

```
<Page ...
      xmlns:my="clr-namespace:My.Control"
      ....>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ProductScrollViewer">
            <StackPanel>
                <my:ProductDataGrid ... 
                        PreviewMouseWheel="ProductDataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel" />

                <my:ProductDataGrid ... 
                        PreviewMouseWheel="ProductDataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel" />

                <my:ProductDataGrid ... 
                        PreviewMouseWheel="ProductDataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

ProductPortfolioListView.xaml.cs:

```
void ProductDataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs args)
{
    ProductScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ProductScrollViewer.ContentVerticalOffset - args.Delta;
    args.Handled = true;
}
```

Note the beauty of this solution lies in the fact that I can separate my DataGrid from the Page that will hold them, so I achieve code isolation as well as less duplicated code. And even better, I absolutely utilize the fact that RoutedEvents keep propragating from the Source to all of its parents until someone handles it (which in my case is my ProductScrollViewer).

Answer (score 8):

It's to late, but I resolved this problem in this manner:
I created the PreviewMouseWheel event for DataGrid 
and manually scrolled the wrapping ScrollViewer

```
private void dgInvoicesItems_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
this.scrInvoice.ScrollToVerticalOffset(this.scrInvoice.ContentVerticalOffset - e.Delta);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**TopMouseScrollPriorityBehavior.TopMouseScrollPriority**

You can simply set the following Attached Property to your `ScrollViewer`

```
public class TopMouseScrollPriorityBehavior
{
    public static bool GetTopMouseScrollPriority(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(TopMouseScrollPriorityProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTopMouseScrollPriority(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TopMouseScrollPriorityProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TopMouseScrollPriorityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TopMouseScrollPriority", typeof(bool), typeof(TopMouseScrollPriorityBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = d as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(TopMouseScrollPriorityBehavior)}.{nameof(TopMouseScrollPriorityProperty)} can only be applied to controls of type {nameof(ScrollViewer)}");
        if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue)
            return;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            scrollViewer.PreviewMouseWheel += ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel;
        else
            scrollViewer.PreviewMouseWheel -= ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    private static void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ScrollViewer b:TopMouseScrollPriorityBehavior.TopMouseScrollPriority="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="5" PanningMode="VerticalFirst">
    <DataGrid ScrollViewer.PanningMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Where b: is the namespace that contains this behavior

**Touch Support**

To enable touch support you might also want to set `ScrollViewer.PanningMode` to `None` on your `DataGrid` and set the same property to `VerticalFirst` or other value on your top level `ScrollViewer`

**Example**

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="5" PanningMode="VerticalFirst">
    <DataGrid ScrollViewer.PanningMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Elegant solution, I like behavior!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the CanContentScroll on the DataGrid to False like this:

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ... />
```

Comment: I already tried that but that didn't help... thank you anyway!